# How to block all outgoing connections using Windows Firewall rules?

Tags: windows

I want to block all outgoing connection. I have created a custom rule:

`C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="blockout" dir="out" action="block" enable="no"`

`C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe advfirewall firewall set rule name="blockout" new enable="yes"`

And it works, but only for web browsers. I would like to block other programs as well, for example Skype.

How can I do that?
How can I override "white-listed" applications?
Is it possible to disable NIC from command-line?

Comment: What is the point in that? If you want to block all outgoing connections pull out the internet cable.(or the wireless card)

Comment: Thanks for help. Pulling out the cable is not an option.

Comment: Disable the NIC? Assign the loopback IP to the NIC?

Comment: Is it possible to disable NIC from commandline?

Comment: @Capa signing in here using the same details as you use to register on Security should allow you to regain control of your question.